# Shortcut key for "reply all" function

Tags: email, mutt

When replying to an email in Mutt, I know that I can reply by just pressing the `r` key. But what if there were other people in the `to` and/or `cc` fields and I would like to reply to all of them?

Long story short, is there any keyboard shortcut in Mutt which corresponds to the "Reply all" function?

Thanks...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Mutt, the "reply all" function is just called "group reply" and you can execute this function by pressing the `g` button.

In `muttrc`, you can create or change the mapping for this:

```
# Reply to all recipients
bind index,pager g group-reply
```